# Postgres timestamp to date

Tags: postgresql, cartodb

I am building a map in CartoDB which uses Postgres. I'm simply trying to display my dates as: 10-16-2014 but, haven't been able to because Postgres includes an unneeded timestamp in every date column.

Should I alter the column to remove the timestamp or, is it simply a matter of a (correct) SELECT query? I can SELECT records from a date range no problem with:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE myTableDate >= '2014-01-01' AND myTableDate < '2014-12-31'
```

However, my dates appear in my CartoDB maps as: 2014-10-16T00:00:00Z and I'm just trying to get the popups on my maps to read: 10-16-2014.

Any help would be appreciated - Thank you!

Comment: Dates in CartoDB are in fact `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` type so as @Craig suggested you need to use `to_char` function to format your date in the form works better for you to be displayed on infowindows or labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing storage with display.

Store a timestamp or date, depending on whethether you need time or not.

If you want formatted output, ask the database for formatted output with `to_char`, e.g.

```
SELECT col1, col2, to_char(col3, 'DD-MM-YY'), ... FROM ...;
```

See [the PostgreSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).

There is no way to set a user-specified date output format. Dates are always output in ISO format. If PostgreSQL let you specify other formats without changing the SQL query text it'd really confuse client drivers and applications that expect the date format the protocol specifies and get something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

You have two basic options.

1  Change the column from a timestamp to a date column.
2  Cast to date in your SQL query (i.e. mytimestamp::date works).

In general if this is a presentation issue, I don't usually think that is a good reason to muck around with the database structure.  That's better handled by client-side processing or casting in an SQL query.  On the other hand if the issue is a semantic one, then you may want to revisit your database structure.

Comment: Ok thanks Chris. I tried casting as you suggested and cannot get this to work. I'm specifically trying this in CartoDB in their popup window on their maps. I tried several varieties of CAST (myTableDate AS DATE) and so on but, no luck.

Comment: Maybe cartodb is doing its own internal processing?

Comment: maybe amend your question to include the \d output of the offending table?